# Reshaping a dask.array in Fortran-contiguous order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, dask

I would like to ask if there is a way how to reshape a `dask` array in [Fortran-contiguous (column-major) order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465377/reshaping-a-numpy-array-in-fortran-contiguous-order) since the parallelized version of the `np.reshape` function is not supported yet ([see here](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/918f2331e923c96a7c769993273c14464ac62aef/dask/array/reshape.py)).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760864/how-do-you-transpose-a-dask-dataframe-convert-columns-to-rows-to-approach-tidy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran-contiguous (column-major) order is simply C-contiguous (row-major) order in reverse. So there's a simple work around for the fact that dask array doesn't support `order='F'`:

- Transpose your array to reverse its dimensions.
- Reshape it to the reverse of your desired shape.
- Transpose it back.

In a function:

```
def reshape_fortran(x, shape):
    return x.T.reshape(shape[::-1]).T
```

Transposing with NumPy/dask is basically free (it doesn't copy any data), so in principle this operation should also be quite efficient.

Here's a simple test to verify it does the right thing:

```
In [48]: import numpy as np

In [49]: import dask.array as da

In [50]: x = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)

In [51]: y = da.from_array(x, chunks=5)

In [52]: shape = (2, 5, 10)

In [53]: np.array_equal(reshape_fortran(y, shape).compute(),
    ...:                x.reshape(shape, order='F'))
    ...:
Out[53]: True
```